# Kubuntu and UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, uefi

I am new to Linux and I just installed Kubuntu. I also have Windows 10 installed.
Everything works fine so far but the only problem is the way in which I have to chose which OS starts.

Right now I have to enter the BIOS and change to UEFI in order to start Windows and if I chose Legacy it will start Kubuntu.

How can I make my computer to boot with UEFI and be able to then select Windows or Kubuntu?

If my setup helps answering this question:

```
I have a SSD on which Windows and Kubuntu are installed:
sda1 - sda4 contain Windows data
sda5       is Kubuntu root

On my HDD I have data.
sdb1 belongs to Windows
sdb2 is Kubuntus /home
```

Comment: So Linux is installed in MBR mode and Windows in UEFI? That's ugly. What *I personally would do if it was my computer* would be wipe it and install everything in MBR mode. UEFI is just a pain in the neck.

Comment: yeah it was the only (or at least easiest) possibility. I do not really want to reinstall Windows... I had to create a Windows installation medium and installing Windows takes some time... Is there no easy and fast solution which does not require to wipe it all?

Comment: I'm sure there is. I was just saying that's what I'd do if it was my PC :)

Comment: I am the opposite. I only run UEFI if possible. Who wants a 35 year old configuration on new hardware. Boot-Repair can convert a BIOS install to UEFI, but you still should have good backups of both Windows & Ubuntu & a Windows repair/recovery flash drive. It actually only un-installs grub-pc(BIOS) and installs grub-efi-amd64(UEFI). What brand/model system. Some are easier than others to use UEFI. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT FORGET TO BACKUP

1. Go to UEFI/BIOS settings
2. Change boot priority. Set '`ubuntu`' to the **top priority** and place 'windows boot manager' as second priority.
3. Enable booting of both UEFI and Legacy os and boot into Kubuntu. You cannot see OS selection screen in Grub because Grub(the default boot-loader for Linux) doesn't know the presence of Windows OS yet. You must update grub to select windows boot-loader during boot.
4. After successfully booting into Kubuntu open a terminal and issue the following command `sudo update-grub` Now Grub will recognise Windows and makes an entry for it.

You should have installed Kubuntu in UEFI mode.